# XPages save datasource - date not being saved

Tags: xpages, datasource

I have some curious behavior on an XPage. Would someone be able to shed some light on this?

In my custom control, I have the datasource defined:

```
<xp:this.data>
<xp:dominoDocument var="incidentDoc" formName="Incident" computeWithForm="onsave" ignoreRequestParams="true">
<xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{javascript:var db = sessionScope.serverPath + "!!" + sessionScope.dbName;
return db;}]]>
</xp:this.databaseName>
</xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
```

Source code for the date field follows. I'm using the eonasdan Bootstrap datepicker.

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <xp:label styleClass="text-muted"  value="Date" id="label2"></xp:label>
                        <br></br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date'
                            id='datetimepicker1'>
                            <xp:inputText styleClass="form-control"
                                readonly="true" value="#{incidentDoc.incidentDate}"
                                id="incidentDate">
                                <xp:this.attrs>
                                    <xp:attr value="Pick a date"
                                        name="placeholder">
                                    </xp:attr>
                                </xp:this.attrs>
                            </xp:inputText>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>

    </div>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
             pickTime: false
            });            
        });         
    </script>
```

And the call to save the datasource is:

```
incidentDoc.save();
```

The incidentDate field in the Notes form is a text field. When I save the datasource, a document gets created with every field on the form populated except the date field.

I've tried setting it to type Date/Time on both the Notes form and the XPage (using the converter) but it does not seem to make a difference. I'm seem to be missing something basic here.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Update: Removing readonly="true" seems to do the trick.

Comment: yep, readonly usually does what it says: mark a control as "readonly"... ;)

Comment: Dan, please add your update as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing readonly="true" seems to do the trick.